# Xubuntu 14.10: wifi dropping out

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, 14.10

My wifi connection keeps failingon xubuntu 14.10 beta2 (I had the same on 11.4, I updated because I read that the kernel update fixed it): it's suddenly unable to connect to anything. If I then disable and re-enable wireless networking, I get this repeatedly in dmesg:

```
[ 6601.635223] wlan0: authenticate with 98:fc:11:79:2c:5c
[ 6601.655253] wlan0: direct probe to 98:fc:11:79:2c:5c (try 1/3)
[ 6601.859117] wlan0: direct probe to 98:fc:11:79:2c:5c (try 2/3)
[ 6602.063204] wlan0: direct probe to 98:fc:11:79:2c:5c (try 3/3)
[ 6602.267407] wlan0: authentication with 98:fc:11:79:2c:5c timed out
```

My wifi is this (from lspci):

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

If anyone knows of any route I can investigate, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution [here on Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=13119513#post13119513)

In short:

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

It disables some power management thing (I don't know the details), and it seems to have fixed my issue (although I think it means my battery drains when on standby :-/ ).

Answer (score 0):

It seems a better solution is coming, and if you want to get your hands dirty you can try building it now:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1240940

Personally, I've just swapped out the wifi module in my laptop until the driver for this one in the standard kernel works a little better :-)